# How do I fingerprint a dynamic URL?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

At http://www.ember-cli.com/asset-compilation/ section **Fingerprinting and CDN URLs** says:

> prepend - Default: '' - A string to prepend to all of the assets.
>   Useful for CDN urls like https://subdomain.cloudfront.net/

What if I have a CNAMES that look like `https://cdn1.foo.com/`, `https://cdn2.foo.com/` and `https://cdn3.foo.com/` that point to my CDN. What do I need to put in the Brocfile to make this work?

The reason why this approach is recommended, is to take advantage of the number of max connections per host name. (more info on that here [Max parallel http connections in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser)).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @ChrisWatts See my anser below. At the moment, this is what I am using. Havent found a way to cycle around the cdn urls though

Answer (score 0):

The way I got this "partially" working on Ember CLI 1.13.X.

I say "partially", because I haven't found a way to cycle across the `cdnX` urls. i.e. `cdn1`, `cdn2`, etc.

In `.ember-cli-build.js`, I have:

```
var emberEnv = process.env.EMBER_ENV;

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    // Add options here
    fingerprint: {
      enabled: ['production', 'staging'].indexOf(emberEnv) > -1,
      prepend: 'https://cdn1' + (emberEnv === 'staging' ? '-staging' : '') + '.site-name.com/dist/team/'
    }
  });
  ...
```